# Разбить массив, на несколько массивов с одинаковыми значениями php

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка, php7

Ломаю голову уже несколько дней , только ничего на php не нашел. 
Суть вопроса 
Есть к примеру массив с фамилиями авторов:
Arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'k', 'a', 'a' , 'b', 'a', 'k'];  - фамилии авторов.
Думаю проще будет сделать вложенный массив 
NewArr{[0]=>['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], [1]=>['b', 'b'], [2]=>['k', 'k']}
Дальше уже код работает с вложенным массивом.

Как разбить массив когда в нем фамилии только две я понимаю, если 3 и больше не могу понять.

Comment: __Проще__ для чего?

Comment: Есть галерея картин, у каждой картины свой автор, при выборе нескольких картин (допустим 10) нужно отсортировать их по авторам и создать PDF файл , имя автора - его картины из тех , которые попали в выборку

Comment: Ну и зачем нужны подмассивы? Разве недостаточно знать фамилию и количество сколько она встречается в массиве?

Comment: Оу, интересная подсказка.

Comment: То есть мне проще ж взять из массива только фамилии авторов , без повторения.  Потом одной фамилией пробежаться по списку картин, внести ид картины к этому автору и так с каждой, я вас верно понял ?

Comment: Может и так, я же не вижу ваших данных. А может например вам создать массив вида `ФИО -> картина`. Или еще чего-нибудь придумать.

Comment: Изначально передается аяксом массив только с id выбранных картин. Пробегаю по массиву с id,  где с БД достаю автора картины. И вот пробегая по массиву с id мы из сразу сортируем под авторов.

Comment: Тогда да - группируете картины по ид автора, по ид получаете авторов и потом можно выводить это как угодно.

Comment: А не проще в запросе сразу все и получить?

Comment: @splash58 так изначально ж не известно ничего кроме id картины

Comment: @u_mulder благодарю за небольшую подсказку, теперь не буду мудровать непонятно что )

Comment: Есть такая штука join

Comment: @splash58 по моему, не то что мне нужно. Человек выше направил меня на нужные действия. Возможно вы не полностью уловили мысль задачи.
Человек выше поймал идею задачи, работаю уже в нужном направлении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'k', 'a', 'a' , 'b', 'a', 'k']; 
$newarr=[];
foreach($Arr as $item ){
  $newarr[$item][]=$item;
}
ksort($newarr);
$result = array_values($newarr);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Тоже немного не то.
Я же сделал по другому.  У меня два массива. Первый - входящий со списком id картин.
Второй  - по каждому id смотрю в БД автора картины и создаю массив с авторами картин, после чего убираю с массива одинаковые значения(повторение фамилии автора). И потом по каждому автору пробегаю по первому массиву и ищу его картины,потом сразу формирую страницу PDF.

Comment: Решение в принципе верно, просто я немного не корректно задал вопрос.
Как упомянул выше, человек меня направил на нужную мысль. Спасибо ему. И вам спасибо. Ваш код тоже пригодится.